# Why 'can', not 'could' in "She told us that we can use the kitchen."?

Tags: backshifting

Why 'can', not 'could' in "She told us that we can use the kitchen."?

I thought that since the main verb is 'told' that the following sentence after 'that~' should use the past tense, 'could', too. Could anybody help me understand what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Can* isn't a verb, it's a *modal*.  So it doesn't have a tense.

Modals modify existing verbs (which don't change tense when used with a modal) and cover situations that don't fit neatly in past or present categories.

Now, often you can substitute *be able to* for can, and often you can substitute *was able to* for could, but *can* and especially *could* have many more uses and meanings.  Basically, *could* isn't strictly a "past form" of *can*.

Things get more complex if you were to throw *have* in there:  You can say *I could have done X*, and *I can't have done X*, but you can't say *I can have done X* (don't confuse this with *I can have X done*).  Because of this *could* is more associated to past tense things than *can* and typically sounds better.

Furthermore, in both your examples, *can*/*could* is probably (guessing without context) really meaning *allowed to*, not *able to*, and *may* would technically be more accurate.  However since modals are often "misused" for politeness and other reasons, no one usually cares.

So use either one; *could* will sound better but it's not wrong to use *can*.

Comment: "(~)probably (guessing without context) really meaning allowed to, not able to, and may would technically be more accurate."            
 Oh, I see :>  I now realize I was preoccupied with the tense part without considering the modal role of 'can/could'..! Thanks for the detailed answer to my Q.   (I am a total newb here and Idk how to 'quote' your reply like the other answer below did ;)

Comment: This is wrong. _Could_, as well as having its own meanings, certainly **does** function as the past of _can_ (and similarly _would_ of _will_). _Could_ would be expected here because the matrix verb is past tense. What is required is to explain why _can_ is also possible.

Comment: *Can* isn't even a verb.  Tense is techincally an invalid concept with it.  That's why you can say things like "I could look into this tomorrow [future]" and "I can see why he stopped [past]".

Answer (score 0):

> She told us that we can use the kitchen [now].
>
> She told us that we could use the kitchen [yesterday].

The modal verbs **can** and **could** represent the ability of a person or thing to do something.

The difference in their usage is that, *could* is used to show that something is possible, **but not certain**, whereas ‘*can*‘ is used to make general statement about what is possible.

For example:

> **They could be at home.** (= Maybe they are at home, maybe they are out.)
>
> **It can be very cold here in winter.** (= It is sometimes very cold here in winter.)

Comment: Is it quite that simple? `She told us [yesterday] that we can use the kitchen [any time we like].`  `She told us [yesterday] that we could use the kitchen [any time we like]`. In both cases 'she told us` in the past that we have the ability to use the kitchen. _When_ we are able to use it is not conveyed. As I see @LawrenceC has mentioned, can/could is not really acting to convey a sense of time. In this context, the sentences are pretty much identical in meaning.

Comment: You're not wrong...